# slide dimensions in r slidy

Tags: r, r-markdown, slidy

Using the default RStudio slidy html presentation template creates slides that have figures with fixed size (I believe 7 inches x 5 inches). When viewing on a larger/higher resolution screen, that can leave a lot of empty space (zooming only changes the size of the text, not the figure):

[image]

But adding `knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, out.width = '100%')` to an R chunk in order to auto-scale the figure size results in a figure that's too tall and requires scrolling to see all the content:

[image]

Using `out.height='100%'` instead of `out.width='100%'` seems to revert to the original size without changing the figure dimensions:

[image]

Is there a better way to control slide dimensions and/or the size of content on html slides other than manually specifying the size of content in inches? When I look at example slides online, they all fill the screen very nicely ([e.g.](https://www.w3.org/Talks/Tools/Slidy2/#(1))). How does one go about actually accomplishing that? Or is the "solution" to just use PDF output?

For reference, here is the default slidy presentation code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: slidy_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown presentation. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document.

## Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

## Slide with R Output

```{r cars, echo = TRUE}
summary(cars)
```

## Slide with Plot

```{r pressure}
plot(pressure)
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a knitr hook to enclose the figure in a `div` tag with class `myfigure`:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::knit_hooks$set(myfigure = function(before, options, envir) {
  if(before) {
    "<div class='myfigure'>"
  } else {
    "</div>"
  }
})
```
````

Then, using CSS, define the height of the elements having the `myfigure` class in the `vh` unit (percentage of the viewport):

````
```{css}
.myfigure { 
  height: 75vh;
}
```
````

Now use this stuff as follows:

````
```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, out.width="100%", out.height="100%", myfigure=TRUE}
plot(pressure)
```
````

Better, instead of using the same height for all elements having the `myfigure` class, you can define this hook which allows to set the height in the chunk options:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::knit_hooks$set(myfigure = function(before, options, envir) {
  if(before) {
    sprintf("<div class='myfigure' style='height:%svh'>", options$myheight)
  } else {
    "</div>"
  }
})
```
````

And use this hook as follows (remove the above CSS chunk):

````
```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, out.width="100%", out.height="100%", myfigure=TRUE, myheight="75"}
plot(pressure)
```
````

Comment: Thanks! That does work to constrain the figure size, but it also warps the figure: https://imgur.com/Es4yGc3

Comment: @filups21 You can try the CSS `.myfigure img { object-fit: scale-down; }` to respect the aspect ratio, but then you don't fully control width & height.

Comment: How do you combine `.myfigure img { object-fit: scale-down; }` with your second option in your response?

Comment: @filups21 put this code in a CSS chunk, as in the first option